# Convertir un String en un documento TXT a un arreglo

Tags: c++, array, string, caracteres

Programa en C++ que lea un archivo plano (micodigo.txt) con la secuencia
ATCGGATCGCCAATGCGGATGCTTTATAATCCGTA#   (*Es un archivo creado en bloc de notas con el nombre micodigo.txt y se encuentra en la carpeta donde mi compilador guarda los cpp y exe*)

El programa debe almacenar la secuencia en un arreglo de tipo char leyéndolo letra por letra del archivo e imprimir en pantalla

Nota: debe usar memoria dinámica

He logrado crear la memoria dinamica con el tamaño de la secuencia, pero no pude convertirla a un vector tipo char con funcion `toCharArray`, esta funcion deberia convertir la cadena, pero en vez de eso solo llena el vector de una sola letra en todas sus posiciones

````
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
class secuencia
{
    private:
        int c,i;
        char l,*arr,*p;
    public:
        secuencia();
        ~secuencia();
        void Abrir();
        
} ;
secuencia::secuencia(){
    c=i=0;
    ifstream salida ("micodigo.txt");
        while(!salida.eof()) 
        {
            c=c+1;
            l=salida.get();
            
        }
    arr = new char [c];
    if(arr==NULL)
    cout<<" Error"<<endl;
}
secuencia::~secuencia(){
    delete arr;
    cout<<"\nSaliendo del programa..."<<endl;
}
void secuencia::Abrir()
{
        ifstream salida ("micodigo.txt");
        while(!salida.eof()) 
        {
            c=c+1;
            l=salida.get();
            cout<<l<<" ";
            for(i=0;i<c;i++)
               arr[i] = l.toCharArray();
        }
        
}
int main()
{   
    secuencia archivo;
    
    archivo.Abrir();
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Tengo unas cuantas preguntas... ¿Porque tu constructor y método `Abrir()` son tan similares?¿Porqué abres e intentas recorrer el archivo en ambos?¿De dónde proviene tu función `toCharArray`, la invocas como un método del tipo char? ¿Dices que *He logrado crear la memoria dinamica con el tamaño de la secuencia*, me puedes explicar dónde haces eso?¿Qué almacenan todos esos miembros privados de tu objeto? Podrías explicarnos mejor que hace tu código, de paso te recomiendo leer la [documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/) de `ifstream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te estás complicando demasiado la vida. El objeto `secuencia` no proporciona absolutamente ninguna ventaja en tu código y complica el diseño del mismo.

Lo primero es calcular el tamaño de la secuencia. Para ello podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
std::ifstream file = std::ifstream("micodigo.txt");

file.seekg(0, file.end);
int const length = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, file.beg);
```

Este truco funciona porque en ASCII todos los caracteres ocupan exactamente 8 bits. Si el archivo no fuese ASCII (por ejemplo utf-8) entonces tendríamos que buscar otra manera de calcular el tamaño ya que la longitud de los caracteres sería variable.

Vale, ya tenemos la longitud de la secuencia ... vamos a reservar la memoria que necesitamos para almacenar el contenido del archivo:

```
char * sequence = new char[length+1]{0};
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que en C++ las cadenas de caracteres terminan con `\0`, luego a la longitud de la secuencia debemos agregarle una posición adicional. El enunciado te dice que hay que leer caracter a caracter, pero no dice nada acerca de cómo imprimir la secuencia leída, así que la trataremos como una cadena de caracteres.

Precisamente, la parte `{0}` es la que indica que todas las posiciones del array deben inicializarse en 0 (Recordemos que `\0` es un 0 expresado en 8 bits). Esto lo hacemos para garantizar que el array termina en `\0`

Vale, ya podemos leer el contenido del archivo.

```
for( char* ptr = sequence; !file.eof(); ++ptr )
{
    file.get(*ptr);
}
```

El método `get()` está sobrecargado. En tu caso estás usando una sobrecarga que te devuelve un `int`. Esa función está pensada principalmente para archivos binarios. En tu caso lo que estás leyendo es un char, luego es preferible usar la sobrecarga de mi respuesta.

A la hora de leer archivos hay que tener en cuenta que el flag `eof` no se activa hasta que no se produce una lectura errónea, es decir, si nuestro archivo tiene únicamente un caracter, el flag `eof` se activará en la segunda llamada a `file.get(*ptr)`. Esta segunda llamada no modificará `*ptr`.

Este comportamiento te daría problemas en tu programa, ya que estás haciendo uso del dato leído sin verificar el flag (asumiendo que tu código funcionase):

```
l=salida.get();               // <<--- Si la lectura es errónea
cout<<l<<" ";
for(i=0;i<c;i++)
   arr[i] = l.toCharArray();  // <<--- procesas `l` igualmente
```

El caso es que este código presenta otros errores. Por ejemplo, el tipo `char` **no tiene** métodos (y tampoco se le pueden agregar). Es decir la llamada a `toCharArray()` es a todas luces incorrecta.

Volviendo al ejercicio, el siguiente paso sería imprimir los datos leídos

```
std::cout << sequence;
```

Facil y rápido. Como hemos generado una cadena de caracteres con su correspondiente finalizador de cadena podemos imprimir toda la secuencia del tirón.

Paso final, liberar la memoria:

```
delete[] sequence;
```

Aquí vemos otra diferencia respecto a tu código:

```
delete arr;
```

Esos dos corchetes son más importantes de lo que parece, ya que tu intención no es eliminar un `char` sino una secuencia de elementos de tipo `char`. La regla es sencilla, si la reserva tiene corchetes, el `delete` debe tenerlos también, es decir:

```
// Sin corchetes
int* ptr1 = new int;
delete ptr1;

// Con corchetes
int* ptr2 = new int[10];
delete[] ptr2;
```

Answer (score 0):

La variable *l* es de tipo char con capacidad para un único carácter, y el método *iftream::get()* igualmente devuelve un único carácter. Por ésta razón no se guardan los demás caracteres: Cada carácter leído susttuye al anterior en *l*.

Por otro lado, char es un tipo atómico; se puede guardar directamente en la siguiente posición de memoria disponible en el búfer *arr*, ya que *arr* es un apuntador a espacios de memoria para chars, pues `arr = new char [c]` en el constructor ya creó un arreglo de char, y *arr* quedó apuntando a su primer elemento.

Para saber dónde en *arr* se debe guardar el carácter, hay dos formas: Tener un apuntador auxiliar *p* que siempre apunte a la siguiente posición libre en *arr* (se inicia con `p=arr;`, se guarda con  `*p=c;`) o bien un contador n que diga el número de la posición (se inicia con `n=0;` y se guarda con `arr[n]=c;`). Luego de guardar, incrementar el apuntador o el contador.

No es necesario que exista entonces un "convertidor" de char a arreglo de char (como no es necesario convertir un int para guardarlo en un arreglo de int).

Así, `arr[n] = c` sería como `*(arr+i) = c` y se leería "guarda el valor de *c* en el espacio de memoria *n* lugares después de donde apunta *arr*", es decir, el n-avo elemento del arreglo *arr[]* comenzando en cero.

---

Recomiendo el sitio http://cplusplus.com para referencias de las funciones y ejemplos de uso de streams.